# ASCII character to decimal code value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ascii

I'm trying to grab a character from a UITextField and find the ascii decimal code value for it. I can save the field value into a char variable, but I'm having trouble obtaining the decimal code value. See below code snippet of the problem.

```
//    grabs letter from text field 
char dechar = [self.decInput.text characterAtIndex:0]; //trying to input a capital A (for example)
NSLog(@"dechar: %c",dechar); // verifies that dechar holds my intended letter
//    below line is where i need help
int dec = sizeof(dechar);
NSLog(@"dec: %d",dec); //this returns a value of 1
//    want to pass my char dechar into below 'A' since this returns the proper ASCII decimal code of 65
int decimalCode = 'A';
NSLog(@"value: %d",decimalCode); // this shows 65 as it should
```

I know going the other way I can just use...

```
int dec = [self.decInput.text floatValue];
char letter = dec;
NSLog(@"ch = %c",letter); //this returns the correct ASCII letter
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `sizeof` operator?

Simply do:

```
int dec = dechar;
```

This will give you `65` for `dec` assuming that `dechar` is `A`.

BTW - you really should change `dechar` to `unichar`, not `char`.

Comment: This worked! I had tried this line before but until I used the unichar instead of char it did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iOS uses unicode, not ASCII. Unicode characters are usually 16 bits, not 8 bits.

Look at using the NSString method characterAtIndex, which returns a unichar. A unichar is a 16 bit integer rather than an 8 bit value, so it can represent a lot more characters.

If you want to get ASCII values from an NSString, you should first convert it to ASCII using the NSString method dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, then iterate through the bytes in the date you get back.

Note that ASCII can only represent a tiny fraction of unicode characters though.

Comment: Thanks for the insight for the noob, however the earlier answer worked for my intentions. I'll keep this in mind for similar future work. Cheers!